# npm / git fails with: refusing to work with credential missing host field

Tags: git, npm, ssl-certificate, npm-install, git-for-windows

I need to install a dependency from git like this:

`npm i  git://hostname.com/scm/projects/project.name.git#tag123`

unfortunatly it fails with:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://hostname.com/scm/projects/project.name.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: refusing to work with credential missing host field
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

my `.git-credentials` looks like this:

```
https://username:password@hostname.com/
```

and `.gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[https]
[http "https://hostname.com"]
    sslCert = D:/git/ssl.crt
    sslKey = D:/git/ssl.key
    sslVerify = false
[url "https://hostname.com/"]
    insteadOf = git://hostname.com/

[core]
    longpaths = true
[credential]
    helper = store
```

---

What is wrong here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Delete the git installation folder (e.g.: `C:\Program Files\Git`) completely  and install the latest git version from https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Seems like a git interanl config get corrupt.